# Difference between minimum sdk target sdk and android build project

Tags: android

I'm confused about I want to run my app all version of mobile from 2.2 to 4.4. The problem is I'm confused what values I set in minimum sdk target sdk and android project build target can anyone help me what is difference between all three can any one help me thank you.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android target sdk 15
/>
```

What is difference between minimum target and project build

Answer (score 1):

Read by Your self . [Developer.google.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

`android:minSdkVersion`

An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute. You should always declare this attribute.

`android:targetSdkVersion`

An integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion.
This attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version. The application is still able to run on older versions (down to minSdkVersion).

As Android evolves with each new version, some behaviors and even appearances might change. However, if the API level of the platform is higher than the version declared by your app's targetSdkVersion, the system may enable compatibility behaviors to ensure that your app continues to work the way you expect. You can disable such compatibility behaviors by specifying targetSdkVersion to match the API level of the platform on which it's running. For example, setting this value to "11" or higher allows the system to apply a new default theme (Holo) to your app when running on Android 3.0 or higher and also disables screen compatibility mode when running on larger screens (because support for API level 11 implicitly supports larger screens).

There are many compatibility behaviors that the system may enable based on the value you set for this attribute. Several of these behaviors are described by the corresponding platform versions in the Build.VERSION_CODES reference.

To maintain your application along with each Android release, you should increase the value of this attribute to match the latest API level, then thoroughly test your application on the corresponding platform version.

Introduced in: API Level 4

Answer (score 0):

android:minSdkVersion the minimum version of android that can support the application
 android target sdk : the android version that you use to build your project

Answer (score 0):

`android:minSdkVersion` means the min sdk android version on which your app allow to run

ans  `android target sdk` means the max sdk android version on which your app allow to run

but i insist you `don't take max  or target sdk` because if u launch your app and after any version of android coming then your app will have prob with that sdk